# Find the codes of dealers who sell a certain part to all projects

Tags: sql

I have a table "**stats**" that consists ****3** ids**.

**IDs:** id_seller, id_part and id_proj

From this table, I want to return **id_sellers** that sell a **certain part** to **all projects.**

**In other words:** **return** id_seller **which** id_part **has all** id_projs values.

[image]

The **result** should look like this:

In the table, id_part **value P3 is the only part** that has all id_projs values **WHICH** are all ('J1', 'J2', 'J3', 'J4', 'J5', 'J6', 'J7').

test code:

```
SELECT id_seller, id_part, id_proj
FROM stats
WHERE id_seller = 'S2' AND id_part = 'P3' AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM stats
      WHERE id_proj IN ('J1', 'J2', 'J3', 'J4', 'J5', 'J6', 'J7'));
```

[image]

I have tried subqueries, Having count, cases ext. to solve the problem, but with no luck.

Looked for some kind of ONLY IN keywords, that would return id_parts that **only** contain all values. not if they contain only one or some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably better solutions, but I think something like this should work:

```
SELECT s.id_seller
FROM stats s
WHERE s.id_part = 'P3'
AND 
(
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_proj)
   FROM stats s2
   WHERE s2.id_seller = s1.id_seller
   AND s2.id_part = s1.id_part
) = 7
```

Comment: Your solution works. Thank you :). I did just a small improvement. Added DISTINCT before s.id-seller so it returns only one S2 AND replace 'P3' with '&part', so i can input difrent parts(P).

Comment: Also insted of = 7, I write (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT(id_proj))
    FROM stats); in case if the data changes.